# Too many DML statemnts 151 in Future apex

Tags: apex, trigger, future

I am getting Too many DML statemnts 151 IN MY aPEX JOB SECTION

[image]

Due to this code

```
public class LeadFuture_TradingAccUpdate {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void updateTradingAccounts(Set<Id> ids) {
        System.debug('called');
        List<Lead> leadList = [Select id,ConvertedAccountId,Owner_Name__c,Owner_Email__c,ConvertedContactId,OwnerId,IsConverted from Lead where ID IN:ids];
        
        Map<Id,Lead> mapLead = new Map<Id,Lead>();
        if(leadList.size()>0){
            for(Lead lea : leadList){
                if(lea.IsConverted == true){
                    mapLead.put(lea.Id,lea);
                }
            }
        }
        
        List<MT4_Accounts__c> mt4List = [Select id,Lead__c,Account__c,Contact__c from MT4_Accounts__c  where Lead__c IN:ids];
        Set<Id> mtIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(MT4_Accounts__c mt4 : mt4List){
            mtIds.add(mt4.Id);
        }
        
        List<Transaction_DB__c> transactionDbList = [Select id,Trading_Account_Login__c from Transaction_DB__c where Trading_Account_Login__c IN: mtIds];
        Map<Id,List<Transaction_DB__c>> tbdMap = new Map<Id,List<Transaction_DB__c>>();
        if(transactionDbList != null){
            for(Transaction_DB__c sales : transactionDbList){
                List<Transaction_DB__c> l = tbdMap.get(sales.Trading_Account_Login__c);
                
                if (l == null) {
                    l = new List<Transaction_DB__c>();
                    tbdMap.put(sales.Trading_Account_Login__c, l);
                }
                l.add(sales);
            }
        }
        
        List<Mt4_Accounts__c> updatemt4List = new List<Mt4_Accounts__c>();
        List<Transaction_DB__c> updatetbdList = new List<Transaction_DB__c>();
        
        System.debug('mt4List+'+mt4List.size());
        for(Mt4_Accounts__c mt : mt4List){
            if(mt.Lead__c != null && mt.Account__c == Label.Account && mt.Contact__c == Label.Contact){
                if(mapLead.size()>0){
                    Lead lea = mapLead.get(mt.Lead__c);
                    if(lea != null){
                        Mt4_Accounts__c addMt = new Mt4_Accounts__c();
                        if(lea.ConvertedAccountId != null){
                            addMt.Account__c = lea.ConvertedAccountId;
                        }
                        
                        if(lea.ConvertedContactId != null){
                            addMt.Contact__c = lea.ConvertedContactId;
                        }
                        
                        addMt.Id = mt.Id;
                        
                        if(lea.OwnerId != null){
                            addMt.Change_Trading_Account_Owner__c = lea.OwnerId;
                        }
                        
                        addMt.Lead__c = null;
                        
                        updatemt4List.add(addMt);
                        
                        if(tbdMap != null){
                            List<Transaction_DB__c> updlist = tbdMap.get(mt.Id);
                            if(updlist != null){
                                for(Transaction_DB__c tbd : updlist){
                                    Transaction_DB__c tbUpdae = new Transaction_DB__c();
                                    tbUpdae.Id = tbd.Id;
                                    if(lea.OwnerId != null){
                                        tbUpdae.Trading_Acount_owner_email__c = lea.Owner_Email__c ;
                                        tbUpdae.Trading_Account_Owner_Name__c = lea.Owner_Name__c ;
                                        tbUpdae.Trading_Account_Owner_ID__c  = lea.OwnerId ;
                                        
                                        updatetbdList.add(tbUpdae);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.debug('updatemt4List+'+updatemt4List.size());
        
        if(updatemt4List.size()>0){
            Boolean mt4Success = false;
            integer count = 0;
            integer maxTries = 3;
               
            final Integer SLEEP_MSTime = 500;
            while(count<3) {
                try{
                    System.debug('test');
                    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(updatemt4List,false);
                    
                    for(Integer index = 0, size = results.size(); index < size; index++) {
                        if(results[index].isSuccess()) {
                            mt4Success = true;
                            System.debug(results[index].id +' was updated');
                            count=3;
                            
                                                   } 
                    }
                    if(mt4Success == true) {
                         if(updatetbdList.size()>0){
                                Database.SaveResult[] results2 = Database.update(updatetbdList,false);
                            }

                    }
                } catch(Exception e){
                    if (!e.getMessage().contains('UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW')){
                        count=3;
                        throw e;
                    } else {
                        if (++count == maxTries){
                            throw e;
                        } else {
                            sleep(SLEEP_MSTime);
                        }
                    }
              
                    System.debug('Error Message:'+e.getMessage()+'- Cause:'+e.getCause()+ ' -LineNumber -'+e.getLineNumber()+'- StackTraceString-'+
                             e.getStackTraceString()+' - TypeName-'+e.getTypeName()); 
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void sleep(Integer ms) {

        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < start + ms) {
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the whole code, no DML operations are running inside For loop
Please help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop is running endlessly.

Also, generally with a `@future` method, I feel it's best to do as much logic in a preparation method and only really use the `@future` for the actual DML if possible.

Anyway, this statement:

```
for(Integer index = 0, size = results.size(); index < size; index++) {
   if(results[index].isSuccess()) {
       mt4Success = true;
       count=3;
   } 
}
```

Contains a problem. If `results[index].isSuccess()` is not success, then count will not be set to 3.

There is unlikely to be an exception because when you call `Database` methods, all the errors are captured in the results.

So, count never gets incremented and your `while` goes for ever.

I'm not sure exactly where you are going to want to increment the counter, but I think perhaps you will want to reuse some of the retry logic that you have in the exception handler.